# Getting the variables and data in nodejs into an html file

Tags: html, node.js, elasticsearch

I'm new to nodejs and I'm using nodejs to connect to elasticsearch and fetch data from elasticsearch, manipulate it and then put the data into a html file, but the problem is that html is client side and nodejs is server side and I don't know how to connect that.
Here is my Code:
node.js :

```
var counting = 1;
var total = 1;
var elasticsearch = require('C:/Windows/System32/node_modules/elasticsearch');
    var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
        host: 'localhost:9200'
    });

     client.count({index: 'csv_pattern'}, function(err, resp, status) {  
        counting = resp['count'];
    });

        client.search({  

            index: 'csv_pattern',
            body: {
                size : counting
            }
        },
            function (error, response, status) {
                total = response['hits']['total'];    
              });
```

I want to use the variables of node.js file  into a html file, please let me know how do I do that.
Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: http://socket.io is likely what you're looking for. You can also try a native `socket` solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use EJS in node, first install and set the view engine to ejs, just save the html code in output.ejs file instead of output.html and using render function the output is sent to html like below.

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
response.render('output.ejs', {result: JSON.parse(response_data)});
```

in ejs file

```
<tbody>

         <% for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {%>
         <tr>
                <td><%= result[i].paramname %></td>
        </tr>
  <% } %>

 </tbody>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that says, app is not defined. What do I do?

Comment: install express and create app.                                                              const express = require('express'); const app = express();

Comment: Where should I add this piece of code in node.js:app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
response.render('output.ejs', {result: JSON.parse(response_data)});

Comment: app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); -- add this code in the beginning after creating app and  response.render('output.ejs', {result: JSON.parse(response_data)});  -- add this in the response part of your get/post methods.